# setAlarmClock not working

Tags: java, android

I am using an `IntentService` to prepare an alarm and use `setAlarmClock` within it to set the alarm. The `IntentService` Always runs at the proper time and sets the alarm (the icon will show) but the alarm will work about 99 times out of 100. When one alarm fails, every alarm after with a similar `Intent` will fail until you completely close the app (It doesnt matter what the `requestsCode` is in the `PendingIntent`). No matter what, microseconds before the scheduled alarm time this is called:

```
09-19 16:10:59.996 1374-2126/? V/AlarmManager: Expired Alarm result :4
09-19 16:11:00.046 1374-2126/? D/VirtualScreenPolicy: applyVirtualScreenAttrs attrs=VirtualScreenAttrs{mDisplayId=0, mBaseDisplayId=0, mBaseActivity=false}
09-19 16:11:00.046 1374-2126/? D/GameManagerService: identifyGamePackage. com.simplyneededapps.ridealarm
09-19 16:11:00.046 1374-2126/? D/MultiWindowPolicy: Gamemode - return 0,  when calling  identifyForegroundApp(com.simplyneededapps.ridealarm)
09-19 16:11:00.066 1374-2126/? D/ActivityManager: mDVFSHelper.acquire()
09-19 16:11:00.066 1374-2126/? W/ActivityManager: startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.simplyneededapps.ridealarm/.MapAlarm VirtualScreenParam=Params{mDisplayId=-1, null, mFlags=0x00000000)} (has extras) }
09-19 16:11:00.116 23354-23354/? E/CocktailBarPositionManager: Window direction: 0
09-19 16:11:00.116 23354-23354/? I/CocktailBarPositionManager: updateAlphaScreenPosition position is dirty 0
```

If it works the Activity life cycle methods are eventually called (onCreate, onResume, onStart...) after this:

```
09-19 16:45:00.048 1366-2124/? V/WindowManager: addAppToken: AppWindowToken{d09214481 token=Token{fb31868 ActivityRecord{8afbf8b u0 com.simplyneededapps.ridealarm/.MapAlarm t2738}}} to stack=2 task=2738 at 1
```

If it doesnt run the Activity life cycle methods are never called and this is:

```
09-13 10:05:00.379 1366-2124/? I/WindowManager: Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{d83f8b2 ActivityRecord{b762abd u0 com.simplyneededapps.ridealarm/.MainActivity t2491}} appWin=Window{6dec0a u0 d0 com.simplyneededapps.ridealarm/com.simplyneededapps.ridealarm.MainActivity} drawState=4
```

Also usually variations of this:

```
09-19 17:08:00.386 1374-1374/? D/SettingsProvider: isChangeAllowed() : name = next_alarm_formatted
09-19 17:08:00.386 2378-2378/? V/CenterBarWindowService: noteResumeComponent  /arrangeState : 0
09-19 17:08:00.396 2302-2302/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleTimeUpdate
09-19 17:08:00.396 1374-2587/? D/StatusBarManagerService: setIconVisibility slot=alarm_clock visible=false
09-19 17:08:00.406 2302-2302/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
09-19 17:08:00.406 2302-2302/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleTimeUpdate
09-19 17:08:00.416 1374-2628/? D/ActivityManager: post active user change for 0 fullscreen true isFloatingActivity() false isHomeActivity() false
09-19 17:08:00.416 1374-2628/? D/KnoxTimeoutHandler: postActiveUserChange [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is false
09-19 17:08:00.426 1374-1374/? D/GameManagerService: NotifyRunnable. pkg: com.simplyneededapps.ridealarm, type: 4, isMinimized: false, isTunableApp: false
09-19 17:08:00.426 1374-1374/? D/GameManagerService: do nothing. mKillNotiCount: 3
09-19 17:08:00.426 2302-2302/? D/Clock: received broadcast android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
09-19 17:08:00.436 1374-1374/? D/KnoxTimeoutHandler: handleActiveUserChange [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is false
09-19 17:08:00.446 1374-1374/? I/KnoxTimeoutHandler: Shared devices show user statefalse
09-19 17:08:00.486 1374-2587/? V/WindowStateAnimator: Finishing drawing window Window{c666b94 u0 d0 com.simplyneededapps.ridealarm/com.simplyneededapps.ridealarm.MainActivity}: mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN
09-19 17:08:00.506 18924-18924/com.simplyneededapps.ridealarm V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{11d12c8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@98ab18f {com.simplyneededapps.ridealarm/com.simplyneededapps.ridealarm.MainActivity}} show : true
09-19 17:08:00.506 18924-18924/com.simplyneededapps.ridealarm I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@98ab18f time:64852633
09-19 17:08:00.546 2302-2302/? D/DateView: received broadcast android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
```

In my IntentService:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        //about 200 lines setting up the alarm

                        AlarmManager alarmMgr;
                        PendingIntent pIntent;

                        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context2.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(context2, MapAlarm.class);
                        intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        intent2.putExtra("id",id) 

                       pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context2, (int) id, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmClockInfo = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(next,pIntent);
                            alarmMgr.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo,pIntent);
                        }else{
                            alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, next, pIntent);
                            }
                stopService(intent);
}
```

Is there a way to always make sure `onCreate` or at least `onResume` is always called no matter what? I still cannot pin down the direct cause so any and all help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Any help or even guesses to the solution would be very helpful. I upgraded everything (Android Studio, TargetSDK version 24 now, my phone software) and I still get the same problem appearing.  The only difference is that the debugger is working better. It also would be helpful to know if others are having a similar problem. Thanks!

Comment: Have you found out the problem?